# Apple Push Notifications dropped from Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have developed a ASP.NET MVC web application that exposes several APIs. One such API is to send a push notification via apple APNS to users. In my c# code i run parallel tasks for each notification that should be sent out. We are then calling Apple APIs direct. Some users are complaining that intermittently they do not receive push notifications. I wanted to know if there are some things to be aware of when attempting to send push notifications from Azure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might help to edit your question and show the code you're using for generating push notifications. Otherwise, it's just a guessing game.

Comment: "Keep your connections with APNs open across multiple notifications; do not repeatedly open and close connections. APNs treats rapid connection and disconnection as a denial-of-service attack." https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingwithAPNs.html